# uniqueness of os.getpid in multiprocessing

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, pid

I run a process distirbuted over the cores through concurrent.futures. Each of the processes has a function which ultimately calls `os.getpid()`. Might the IDs from `os.getpid()` coincide in spite of being in different concurrent.futures' branches?

Comment: On my ubuntu system, the pid table is 4,194,304 unique entries. Pids will be reused after that. I'm not sure what the rotation rate on Windows is. A 32 bit machine will likely have 32K or fewer entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that the meaning of the value returned by `os.getpid()` is well defined. I'm pretty sure that you can depend on no two *running* processes having the same ID, but it's very likely that after some process is terminated, it's ID eventually will be re-used.

That's what happens in most operating systems, and the implementation of `os.getpid()` quite likely just calls the operating system and returns the same value.

Comment: so concatenation of time and pid should give a unique identifier if i understand correctly.

Comment: @guyguyguy12345 - It depends on how unique this identifier needs to be. If you do this twice within a timer tick, then it fails on a single machine. You could add a global counter to fix it. If you do this on a large cluster of machines, there is a chance that two will generate the same number in there somewhere. If that small risk is a problem, then something like `secrets.token_bytes()` may be better.

Comment: the implementation of `os.getpid` uses the C getpid function. See the [source for posix systems](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/930d5377c5877a631c3c23929e2cb6211bb0e2fb/Modules/posixmodule.c#L6847-L6860). having trouble finding it for windows